# Displaying a button when the character counter reaches 100

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to do a quizz page and I need for my "Submit" button to appear once the minimum number of characters have been written in the textarea. Here is what I tried but couldn't get it to work.

```
<textarea  name="tweet" id="textbox"
          rows="13" cols="70" placeholder="" maxlength="250"></textarea><br>
        <span id="char_count">0/250</span>

        <script>
        let textArea = document.getElementById("textbox");
        let characterCounter = document.getElementById("char_count");
        const minNumOfChars = 0;
        const maxNumOfChars = 250;
        var text = document.getElementById("buton");
        const countCharacters = () => {
          let numOfEnteredChars = textArea.value.length;
          let counter = minNumOfChars + numOfEnteredChars;
          characterCounter.textContent = counter + "/250";
        };
        textArea.addEventListener("input", countCharacters);
        if (counter > 100 ) {
            text.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
        }
        </script>

              <br><br><br>
              <div>
                <button class="NextStep" id="buton" style="display:none"
                onclick="NextStep()">Finalizare Curs</button>
              </div>
              <script>
             function NextStep() {
                 location.href =("Cursuri.html")
             }
             </script>
```

Comment: `couldn't get it to work.`; does it do anything? Is there an error in your dev console? You seem to be defining `counter` within `countCharacters()`, but then you're attempting to access it from outside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has all the necessary parts to work but you have restructured it like a Picasso painting!. With some cut-copy-paste in the right place, it works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>ΤΙΤΛΟΣ</title>
   </head>

   <body style="background-color: burlywood;">
      <textarea name="tweet" id="textbox" rows="13" cols="70" placeholder="" maxlength="250"></textarea><br>
      <span id="char_count">0/250</span>
      <br><br><br>
      <div>
         <button class="NextStep" id="buton" style="display:none" onclick="NextStep()">Finalizare Curs</button>
      </div>
      <script>
         let counter
         let textArea = document.getElementById("textbox")
         let characterCounter = document.getElementById("char_count")
         const minNumOfChars = 0
         const maxNumOfChars = 250
         let text = document.getElementById("buton")
         const countCharacters = () => {
            let numOfEnteredChars = textArea.value.length
            counter = minNumOfChars + numOfEnteredChars
            characterCounter.textContent = counter + "/250"
            if (counter > 100) {
               text.style.display = "block"
            }
            else {
               text.style.display = "none"
            }
         }
         textArea.addEventListener("input", countCharacters)
         function NextStep() {
            location.href = ("Cursuri.html")
         }
      </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Sorry for the abstract code, did my best !

Answer (score 0):

First, always make sure to place the script tag at the end of the body tag so that it will wait to first fully load the DOM tree before moving in to script part.

Second, you seem to be wanting to keep track of `counter` variable, and change the button style based on that. But as @mykaf said, you have declared it wrongly inside the `countCharacters` function, so it cannot be accessed outside of that function. Read about [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of variable.

Third, you need to check if value of `counter` is greater than 100 each time it is changed, but currently you have put the `if-else` part which checks this, outside of the `countCharacters` function. So effectively, `counter` value is getting increased but it is not being checked if greater than 100. So you have to also move that `if-else` part inside the `countCharacters` function.

Overall, your script tag should looks something like this

```
<script>
  let textArea = document.getElementById("textbox");
  let text = document.getElementById("buton");
  let characterCounter = document.getElementById("char_count");
  const minNumOfChars = 0;
  const maxNumOfChars = 250;
  let counter;
  const countCharacters = () => {
    let numOfEnteredChars = textArea.value.length;
    counter = minNumOfChars + numOfEnteredChars;
    characterCounter.textContent = counter + "/250";
    if (counter > 100) {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      // else part here
    }
  };
  textArea.addEventListener("input", countCharacters);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your code. You need to check the value of **counter** inside the **countCharacters** function and also make sure to declare the **counter** variable outside the function but within the same scope. Here's the corrected code:

```
<textarea
      name="tweet"
      id="textbox"
      rows="13"
      cols="70"
      placeholder=""
      maxlength="250"
    ></textarea
    ><br />
    <span id="char_count">0/250</span>

    <script>
      let textArea = document.getElementById("textbox");
      let characterCounter = document.getElementById("char_count");
      const minNumOfChars = 0;
      const maxNumOfChars = 250;
      let button = document.getElementById("buton");
      let counter;

      const countCharacters = () => {
        let numOfEnteredChars = textArea.value.length;
        counter = minNumOfChars + numOfEnteredChars;
        characterCounter.textContent = counter + "/250";

        if (counter > 100) {
          button.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          button.style.display = "none";
        }
      };

      textArea.addEventListener("input", countCharacters);
    </script>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <div>
      <button
        class="NextStep"
        id="buton"
        style="display: none"
        onclick="NextStep()"
      >
        Finalizare Curs
      </button>
    </div>
    <script>
      function NextStep() {
        location.href = "Cursuri.html";
      }
    </script>
```

This code will properly show the "Finalizare Curs" button when the character count is above 100, and hide it when it's below 100.